# Is it possible to have Firefox use more than 1 CPU core in Windows?

Tags: firefox, cpu, performance, browser, speed

According to the Microsoft Windows *Task Manager*, [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/new/) tends to just use 1 CPU core for most of its processing.

When a system isn't running any foreground tasks besides Firefox, this leaves much processor power unused.

Is it possible to have Firefox use more than 1 CPU core (either virtual or physical cores)?

Comment: Firefox already run in multiple processes since FF 48. I don't see it consumes only 1 CPU

Comment: Are you perhaps misinterpreting the situation? Does Firefox actually have enough work to put multiple cores to use? Keep in mind that Javascript, for example, is single-threaded.

Comment: Firefox already uses multiple cores and is multi-threaded.  if I am not mistake, every single tab is actually it's own process, this is done for security and performance reasons.  I suspect you are not reading the results from Task Manager correctly (or perhaps it's simplifying the situation.

Comment: I would be annoyed if WEBPAGES required multiprocessing. => High CPU load, hot computer, fans busy all the time... further; if a webpage requires more than minimal CPU power I tend to not visit that place more than once; because then it is "faulty" in my opinion.

Comment: @DanielB You mentioned that JavaScript is single-threaded.  To confirm, does that mean a webpage can literally only have a single thread of JavaScript running at once, and that the thread will only run a single core?

Comment: @Ramhound I think you may be correctly explaining what I'm seeing.  If I'm interpreting what you wrote correctly, a slow and bloated web page with many scripts (Amazon is a classic example) will then only run on a single CPU core, resulting in poor performance.  It sounds like the multi-threaded capabilities of Firefox (and likely all other web browsers) **largely** only come into play if multiple tabs are open.

Comment: @Hannu I guess that leaves out Amazon, Gmail, YouTube, Google Sheets, Microsoft Live, Yahoo, Reddit, Zoho, and a host of other popular websites that use large amounts of CPU power.  At least you can still use faqs.org ! ;)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket And I'll probably not surprise you now; The only one of those that I actually frequent is Youtube. The others and similar ones have *nothing* to offer me. And I will most likely stick to that opinion much longer than I already have (I've been on the internet since the early 90's).